# Core update installs 8.6.0-beta1 instead of 8.5.6

Tags: 8, updating

Using composer I tried to update Drupal 8 to 8.5.6. The update wasn't working, so I changed the dependencies to explicitly require 8.5.6. The update began, but it installed Drupal 8.6.0-beta1. The command I used was `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies -v`.

The updates page still says Drupal 8.5.6 is required. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Should I try to roll it back? I tried requiring Drupal 8.6.0-beta2 and Drupal 8.6.0-rc1, but an error suggested not to update to these versions. I want the site live ASAP, and updated to Drupal 8.5.6.

Comment: What does `composer why 8.6.0-beta1` and `composer why-not 8.5.6` say?

Comment: I bet my dinner that this is being caused by `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in your `composer.json`. Change it to ``"minimum-stability": "stable"`` or `alpha` or `beta`, whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Your right it does say "dev". I'm at beta1 what command should I use to get to a stable release suitable for production please?

Comment: As already said, simply change it to `"stable"`. Then save the file, then `composer update` again. If that doesn't work, delete `composer.lock`, delete the `/vendor` folder and then `composer install` again.

Comment: I'd tried changing to stable and 8.5. It looked like it was going to revert to 8.5.5 but running the database update lost the site. I then tried Beta2 but that didn't work either so I tried stable and beta1 to try to rescue the situation hence being back to beta1. Deleting folders makes me nervous so I'll double check my recent backup works first and give it a whirl tomorrow when I'm feeling brave. Many thanks

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably should test that with a database backup from before you updated to 8.6.0-beta1. On the other hand, 8.6.0 should actually going to be released ... today ... https://www.drupal.org/core/roadmap. So, hey, maybe tomorrow you can simply update to 8.6.0 stable and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me was start from 8.5.0, upgrade to 8.5.5 then run:

```
composer update drupal/core symfony/* --with-dependencies
```

I'm now on 8.6.0 ! :)

Comment: And you changed `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to `stable`, didn't you?

Comment: Composer will pick a stable version over an unstable one if it's available @leymannx. No need to change minimum stability for this. For example I have a project with min stability dev, drupal/core required at ~8.5, and `composer update` gets me to stable `8.6.0`.

Comment: Yes I changed to "stable". On the other project I'm developing I'll experiment with both "stable" and "dev". thanks both.